# OpenIE did not get the same result as it said in the demo

Tags: stanford-nlp

I just download and have a try of the OpenIE. I use the same sentence in the demo "Born in a small town, she took the midnight train going anywhere."

In this page:[enter link description here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/openie.shtml#Mail) it said there will be three triplets extracted, but from below it missing the triplet "she took midnight train". This information is important.

Could you tell me why I can't get the same result as in the demo?
Is there any parameter need to be set?

Thanks.

```
tom@tom-Aspire-E5-572G:~/Downloads/stanford-corenlp-full-2015-12-09$ cat input.txt
Born in a small town, she took the midnight train going anywhere.
tom@tom-Aspire-E5-572G:~/Downloads/stanford-corenlp-full-2015-12-09$ java  -cp "*" -Xmx1000m edu.stanford.nlp.naturalli.OpenIE ./input.txt
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator tokenize
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator ssplit
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator pos
Reading POS tagger model from edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger ... done [2.6 sec].
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator lemma
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator depparse
Loading depparse model file: edu/stanford/nlp/models/parser/nndep/english_UD.gz ... 
PreComputed 100000, Elapsed Time: 2.157 (s)
Initializing dependency parser done [5.1 sec].
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator natlog
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator openie
Loading clause searcher from edu/stanford/nlp/models/naturalli/clauseSearcherModel.ser.gz...done [0.73 seconds]
Processing file: ./input.txt
All files have been queued; awaiting termination...
1.0 she Born in small town
1.0 she Born in town
DONE processing files. 0 exceptions encountered.
```

Comment: Still did not get any answer.
"Born in a small town, she took the midnight train going anywhere." Anyone can also have a test of such sentence to see if it also missed the information?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to chalk this up to the parse tree being difficult. The underlying dependency parser -- and in fact, the underlying dependency representation -- changed between the publication of the paper and the most recent release of the code. For instance, "Born in a small town, she took the midnight train." works ok.

Comment: Thanks for help. Just tried it worked for your modified sentence, I may try older version in future.